# Pattern matching with pinned variables fail

Tags: elixir

Why this pattern matching passes:

`%{"asd" => %{}} = %{"asd" => %{"qwe" => ""}}`

while this one doesn't (MatchError):

`x = %{}
 %{"asd" => ^x} = %{"asd" => %{"qwe" => ""}}`

?

Edit: Found out that the pin operator means that it must be equal to. Now, how can I *match* to the `x` variable in this map?

Comment: You cannot convert a map variable to a pattern (not without `eval` at least). What are you trying to achieve here? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Ok, so a map variable and a pattern is not the same thing. Didn't know that until now :) But it makes sense.

Comment: Answered to your edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Pinned variable values on the left side, by definition, must be equal to corresponding values in the right side ([tutorial](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator)).

So following match will work:

```
x = %{"qwe" => ""}
%{"asd" => ^x} = %{"asd" => %{"qwe" => ""}}
```

Give `x` any other value, and match will fail with `MatchError`.

To assign `x` just omit pin operator, i.e. remove `^`.

Comment: Omiting the pin operator will not match x, it will assign %{"qwe" => ""} to the x variable.

Comment: @Darxis, you are right, I've edited my update to mention "assign", not "match". In this answer the example shows one possible match (for `x = %{"qwe" => ""}`). As I said, with any other `x` value given right side `%{"asd" => %{"qwe" => ""}}` match won't work.